# Weak convergence using tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I haven't got to see this argument used in the PhD thesis of [R. Ryan]: *[Applications of topological tensor products to infinite dimensional holomorphy](https://vdocuments.mx/applications-of-topological-tensor-products-products-to-infinite-dimensional.html?page=1)*, doctoral thesis, Trinity College, Dublin (1980), p. 104:

Considering a reflexive Banach space $E$, we have a net $\{x_i^{(n)}\}_{i\in I}$ in the symmetric tensor product $\bigodot_n E,$ where we denote $x^{(n)}=x\otimes x\ldots \otimes x,$ which converges weakly to some element of $\bigodot_nE,$ and $\|x_i\|\leq 1 \ \forall i.$ Then, in particular,
$$
\widetilde{\phi}^n(x_i^{(n)})=[\phi(x_i)]^n
$$
converges for every $\phi \in E',$ since
$$
\phi^n \in \mathcal{P}(^nE)\cong\Big(\bigodot_nE\Big)^\prime.
$$
So the author concludes that $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a weak Cauchy net in $E$ and consequently, as $E$ is reflexive, it's is weakly convergent.
I don't get to see this because, as far as I know, the convergence of $\{\phi^n(x_i)\}$ doesn't imply the convergence of $\{\phi(x_i)\}$. What I guess is, the hypothesis of the convergence for all $\phi$ is the key: am I right or there's a different reason?

Comment: I don't quite understand your start: "I haven't got to solve...".  Could you add the author, and maybe a link, to the PhD these?  Then people might be able to understand the question in context?  In particular, I don't think there is a single meaning of a symmetric tensor product of _Banach_ spaces, so knowing the definition of this would really help...

Comment: The author of this thesis is Ray Ryan (Galway).